# Как настроить Babel для webpack2 с optional: runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, babel, webpack2

Никак не могу настроить конвертер Babel для webpack2-проекта. Я бы хотел, чтобы webpack добавлял функционал babel в отдельный модуль (в первой версии webpack это прекрасно работало с настройкой `optional: 'runtime'` в `webpack.config.js`), но пока и без этой возможности не получается.

**Структура проекта** Исходники js-файлов в `development/js`, выходной js - пока в `development`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**package.json** (показываю, какие пакеты устанавливал)

```
{
    "name": "Webpack2BabelTest",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "babel-loader": "^6.4.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^2.3.3"
    }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
'use strict';

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

module.exports = {

    context: __dirname + '/development',

    entry: './js/main.js',

    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/development/',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015',
            optional: 'runtime'
        }]
    },

    watch: NODE_ENV === 'development'
};
```

**Ошибка:**

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.loaders[0] has an unknown property 'optional'. These properties are valid:
   object { enforce?, exclude?, include?, issuer?, loader?, loaders?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, query?, resource?, resourceQuery?, compiler?, rules?, test?, use? }
```

**Ошибка без настройки** `optional: 'runtime'` **:**

```
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'babel-core'
```

---

### Обновление

Попробовал решение на основе ответа YozhEzhi . Я убрал всё, что связано с react, поскольку не использую данный движок. Всё отработало без ошибок, но `let` в `var` не преобразовалось, значит конвертация не была выполнена.

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.22.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^2.3.3"
  }
```

**webpack.config**

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['babel-loader']
        }
    ]
},
```

[Ссылка на исходники](https://yadi.sk/d/DxvDGV6z3H6Egp)  (для уменьшения объёма архива node_modules выкладывать не стал; их нужно будет установить с помощью `npm i`).

Comment: `npm i -S babel-core`

Comment: Благодарю Вас за указание. К сожалению, при установке недостающего пакета возникает ошибка `couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory ... \\development\\js`, плюс осталось та же ошибка с настройкой `optional: 'runtime'`. Подскажите, как это исправить в Webpack2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel хочет знать - какие пресеты ему использовать.

Пример `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "cool-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "6.22.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.22.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "1.3.1",
    "webpack": "2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.3.0"
  }
}
```

В `webpack.config.js`:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader'],
    },
  ],
},

resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '*'],
},
```

Полёт нормальный без `optional: 'runtime'`.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Ошбики исчезли, но к сожалению, конвертации в старый JS не произошло. Если у Вас есть время и желание довести решение данной проблемы до конца и получить галочку за ответ, пожалуйста посмотрите поле "Обновление" в вопросе.

Comment: Добавил в конфиг настройку `resolve`.

Comment: К сожалению бесполезно. Загрузил исходники на [Яндекс-диск](https://yadi.sk/d/DxvDGV6z3H6Egp) (нужно будет установить пакеты через `npm i`).

Comment: А теперь внимательно посмотрите на мой `package.json`. Бабелю нужно указать `presets`.

Comment: Да! Я ошибся, прошу прощения. И последний вопрос: есть ли необходимость в webpack2 прописывать `optional: 'runtime'`, чтобы функциональность babel не добавлялась в каждый модуль?

Comment: Такой опции я не встречал. "функциональность babel не добавлялась в каждый модуль" - не понял, что имеется в виду. Бабель нужен для того, чтобы ES6 -> ES5. Сам Бабель в модуль не помещается ведь.

Comment: Я узнал об этом из [этого](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-Q7PcfyiGU&list=PLDyvV36pndZHfBThhg4Z0822EEG9VGenn&index=7) урока (можете перемотать на 5:50).

Comment: Ну так ведь там на видео видно как нужно прописать, и что установить. Ну и в комментариях там ссылки на нужные ресурсы.

Comment: Так у меня в поле вопроса всё, как в этом видео, и прописано. В webpack1 всё прекрасно работает, но в webpack2 - нет. Ошибку, вызываемую `optional: 'runtime'`, который добавляет функционал babel в отдельный модуль, я тоже показал в вопросе. Чтобы закрыть этот вопрос, нужно либо узнать, как добиться эффекта `optional: 'runtime'` в новом webpack, либо, если на то есть основания, то сказать, в новой версии babel и webpack в `optional: 'runtime'` нужды нет.

Comment: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/231

Comment: Вообщем, я поэксперементировал и никаких модулей с функционалом babel в выходном файле я не обнаружил. По-видимому, в `webpack2` и новой версии babel нужда в `optional: runtime` отсутствует. Думаю, на этом вопрос можно закрыть. Спасибо Вам за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

По настройке ответ уже дал `YozhEzhi`, а мне остаётся добавить, что в `webpack2` при этих настройках функционала `babel` в модули добавлено не будет. В `webpack1` [это было не так](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-Q7PcfyiGU&list=PLDyvV36pndZHfBThhg4Z0822EEG9VGenn&index=7) (перематываем примерно на 5:50), но теперь `webpack1` разработчиками объявлен `depricated`. Результаты эксперимента:

**main.js**

```
'use strict';

let testVar = 'test';
let testString = `<div>${testVar}</div>`;
```

**index.js** (выходной файл, после функционала webpack):

```
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";


var testVar = 'test';
var testString = '<div>' + testVar + '</div>';

/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```